# AVD in android studio 1 can not connect to internet

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I run the emulator in android studio the internet cannot connect and it appears disconnected in the upper left side.
Also my application does not work properly.

Comment: try restart emulator and wipe cache, try recreate the emulator, try restart your pc. does your pc have an internet connection?
statements are no questions btw and your informations giving are far too less.

Comment: I restart the emulator and wiped cache and do all you mentioned above but it is still diconnected

Comment: In generell the emulator is using the pc's internet connection as 3G. so either you turned that off in the preferences somewhere or your device can't use 3G or something went wrong in the sdk installation.